# Exception thrown by Double.valueOf not consistent

Tags: java, android, exception, numberformatexception

I am working on an android project. I have a question which I am not able to find the answer.
There is a discrepancy in the exception thrown by Double.valueOf

1. Double.valueOf("3e"), throws the exception NumberformartException
2. Double.valueOf("3e5"), DOES NOT throw the same exception.

I checked and found that value of the Double variable for case 2 is 30000.0

Would anyone know the reason why there is difference in behavior.

Comment: What would you expect `3e` to parse to?

Comment: `3e5` means `3*10^5`, where `^` means exponentiation. You can use this constant in regular code (I think; at least in several languages you can)

Answer (score 3):

In this `E` stands for `exponent`. so here

`3e` not a number but `3e5 = 3*10^5`

so `3e5` will not throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error or inconsistency here. `3e5` is a valid input. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.
Actually I was getting confused with e being used as a constant 2.718
and had completely forgotten that 3e5 is notation for 3x10^5.

Thanks once again